# Add 2 coordinates to an index in a list in Python, and algebra

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, append, tuples

I want to have a 2 or 3D list in Python containing endpoints to 10 separate lines where I can pass the y-coordinates as a function of x in range(10). y=((x+1)/2)*x for x in range(10 or however long).

My ultimate goal is to make 10 separate lines with endpoints x 0-10 but the y's would be increasingly further apart, according to the above equation.
I'm not able to do this::

```
for n in range(3):
    listy2[0].append((n,n))
    listy2[1].append((n,n))
```

It returns error lin[0] ... not in index.

I am lost on how to go about this.  Here is what I have so far.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

listy2 = [[] for i in range(3)]

for q in range(3):
    listy2[q].append((0,10))

listy2[0].append((2,2))

listy2[1].append((3,3))

listy2[2].append((4,4))


print('listy2 ' ,listy2)

#THIS IS WHAT LIST LOOKS LIKE
# lines = [ [(0,10),(2,2)] , 
#         [(0,10),(3,3)] , 
#         [(0,10),(4,4)] ]


for li in listy2:

    ax.plot(li[0],li[1])



ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What does that mean you are unable? Do you get an error, unexpected results? More info needed...

Comment: Meaning I don't even know how to go about it.  It added some crazy tuples of 3,3,3, 4,4,4, and 5,5,5 to each list.

Comment: Please make your question clearer by trimming away all irrelevant code to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing to int(n),int(n).  Here is the code and new pic.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')




listy2 = [[] for i in range(10)]

for q in range(10):
    listy2[q].append((0,10))

for r in range(10):
    j = (r+1)*r
    listy2[r].append((int(j), int(j)))


print('listy2 ' ,listy2)


#  HERE IS WHAT LIST OF ENDPOINTS LOOK LIKE
# listy2  [[(0, 10), (0, 0)], 
#        [(0, 10), (2, 2)], 
#        [(0, 10), (6, 6)], 
#        [(0, 10), (12, 12)], 
#        [(0, 10), (20, 20)], 
#        [(0, 10), (30, 30)], 
#        [(0, 10), (42, 42)], 
#        [(0, 10), (56, 56)], 
#        [(0, 10), (72, 72)], 
#        [(0, 10), (90, 90)]]

for li in listy2:

    ax.plot(li[0],li[1])



ax.set_xlabel("x axis")
ax.set_ylabel("y axis")
plt.show()
```